# Можно ли сделать так, чтобы новые версии андроид приложения обновлялись только у пользователей у которых телефон настроен на русский язык?

Tags: android, android-studio

Проблема связана с тем, что приложение дополнено функционалом (новые формы, кнопки, функции, сообщения, контент и т.д.) на русском языке. Нет перевода обновления на другие языки, которые раньше поддерживались (английский, испанский)... Просто нет смысла переводить, т.к. на этих языках мало пользователей

Comment: можно мне кажется сделать в плей маркете чтобы приложение было недоступно для определенных стран и все

Comment: думаю нет проблемы, если остальные пользователя не получат ничего нового

Comment: @Style-7, в том и проблема, что получат, и на непонятном им русском языке.

Comment: @Andrew Goroshko Спасибо. Я знаю об этом, что страны можно фильтровать, но это только частично решит задачу. Потому что в разрешенных странах все равно будут пользователи на разных языках...

Comment: мне кажется можно особо не заморачиваться, кто знает русский язык тот будет пользоваться приложением, а кто не знает (даже в разрешенной стране) то пользоваться соответственное не будет, вы можете конечно решить проблему ограничением регионов, но опять так к примеру в США (или в любой другой стране) есть много русскоговорящей аудитории.